Type function parameter based on other parameters
My final goal is to use useModel hook like this:
useModel(Art, "get", { id: 7 })
useModel(Art, "post", { data: { title: "Art title" } })

But I have problem with correctly typing third parameter of this hook, because it is dependant on method (second parameter). All models have the same methods with the same parameters and are extended from the same class that holds these methods. Methods parameters can be different as shown in code samples below.
class BaseApiModel {
  protected static endpoint = "";
  public static key = "";

  ...

  static async get<T>(id?: number, params?: QueryFilterParams) {
    const axios = this.getAxiosInstance();

    const response: ResourceResponse<T> = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: id ? `${this.endpoint}/${id}` : this.endpoint,
      params,
    });

    // TODO: type the response (ResourceResponse<T> | CollectionResponse<T> | PaginatedResponse<T> | CountResponse)
    return response;
  }

  static async post<T>(data: Omit<T, "id">) {
    const axios = this.getAxiosInstance();

    const response: ResourceResponse<T> = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: this.endpoint,
      data,
    });

    return response;
  }

...

}

This is example model that will be passed to the hook:
class Art extends BaseApiModel {
  protected static endpoint = "/art";
  public static key = "art";

  id!: number;
  title!: string;
  description!: string;
  image?: File;
}

This is the hook:
type Methods = "get" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "delete";
function useModel<T extends typeof BaseApiModel>(
  model: T,
  method: Methods,
  options?: Record<string, any>
) {
  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: [model.key, method, options],
    queryFn: model[method](options),
    enabled: method === "get",
  });

  const mutation = useMutation({
    mutationKey: [model.key, method, options],
    mutationFn: model[method](options),
  });

  if (method === "get") {
    return query;
  }
  return mutation;
}


Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see the problem you're having without seeing unrelated problems. Right now there are a bunch of undeclared/unimported things like QueryFilterParams and getAxiosInstance and useQuery and useMutation. This looks like it depends on third party libraries or private code, neither of which are really the issue you're asking about, right? Unless the question depends on axios, etc., please remove mentions of them in the code. (If it does depend on third-party things, please tag the question as such).

(see prev comment)  Also it's not clear what your problem currently is; it should jump out at us when we look at the code in our IDEs. What is working that shouldn't work or vice versa. Where in the code?

You can use a conditional type for the third argument:
Playground
type Methods = "get" | "post" | "put" | "patch" | "delete";

type QueryFilterParams = Record<string, string>;

function useModel<T extends typeof BaseApiModel, M extends Methods>(
  model: T,
  method: M,
  options?: M extends 'get' ? {id?: number, params?: QueryFilterParams } : M extends 'post' ? {data: Omit<InstanceType<T>, "id"> }  : never
) {
  
}

type ResourceResponse<T> = T;

class BaseApiModel{
  protected static endpoint = "";
  public static key = "";

  static async get<T>(id?: number, params?: QueryFilterParams) {

    const response: ResourceResponse<T> = await axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: id ? `${this.endpoint}/${id}` : this.endpoint,
      params,
    });

    // TODO: type the response (ResourceResponse<T> | CollectionResponse<T> | PaginatedResponse<T> | CountResponse)
    return response;
  }

  static async post<T>(data: Omit<T, "id">) {

    const response: ResourceResponse<T> = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: this.endpoint,
      data,
    });

    return response;
  }
}

class Art extends BaseApiModel{
  title = 'Art title';
}

useModel(Art, "get", { id: 7 })
useModel(Art, "post", { data: { title: "Art title" } })

